Ask the sup in the definition of Cauchy sequence
A sequence of elements $\left\{x_n\right\}$ in a metric space $(\mathbb{M}, d)$ is said to be a Cauchy sequence if $\sup_{m, n \geq N} d\left(x_m, x_n\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.
Question: in the definition, why do we need sup? What if I change the definition to the following:
what if I change sup to all $m,n \geq N$?
It is a Cauchy sequence if for all $ m,n \geq N, d\left(x_m, x_n\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Is this still correct?

You can't let $N\to\infty$ simply if you remove the sup. But you can rephrase it without the definition without sup using an $\epsilon-N$ definition. Indeed, that is a usual definition.

Basically, given $m,n>N$ for some $N,$ it is not true that $m,n>N$ for all $N,$ so it is unclear what you are saying goes to $0$ as $N\to\infty.$

The usual definition is: For all $\epsilon>0,$ there is an $N$ such that for all $m,n>N,$ $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon.$ The definition using $\sup$ is certainly equivalent and briefer, but I think it hides more than it help.

I think this is less efficient but more intuitive: " There exists a function $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R_+$ such that $\lim_{N\to\infty}f(N)=0$, and for all $N$ and $m,n>N$, we have $d(x_m,x_n)<f(N)$. "

This answer is purely from a logical standpoint, I haven't thought about whether your definition of Cauchy sequence is correct.

It is a Cauchy sequence if for all $ m,n \geq N, d\left(x_m, x_n\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Is this still correct?

No. Written a bit more symbollicaly, this would be
$$\forall m,n\geq N:\Big(\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}d(x_m,x_n)=0\Big)$$
But, by writing $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}$, you are introducing a new variable $N$ which has no relation to the $N$ in $\forall m,n\geq N$. So $d(x_m,x_n)$ is just constant with respect to this new variable.
Obviously, that's not what you wanted. You have to somehow "move" the $\forall m,n\geq N$ into the scope of the $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}$. The supremum does exactly that:
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\sup_{m, n \geq N}d(x_m,x_n)\Big)=0.$$

Your definition is a little murky. It doesn't quite make sense as written, due to the unclear dummy variables. Is it,
$$(\forall m, n \ge N)(d(x_m, x_n) \to 0 \text{ as } N \to \infty)?$$
That doesn't make sense, since $d(x_m, x_n) \to 0 \text{ as } N \to \infty$ doesn't make sense on its own, because $m$ and $n$ do not relate to $N$. Or, is it
$$(\forall m, n \ge N, d(x_m, x_n) \to 0) \text{ as } N \to \infty?$$
This also doesn't make sense; $\forall m, n \ge N, d(x_m, x_n) \to 0$ is also nonsensical. It appears to be a predicate in terms of $N$, but there's no way to take a limit of a predicate as $N \to \infty$.
All that said, you could write it a little differently, in a way that I suspect is more in line with your intention:

A sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy if, for any sequence $(m_N)$ and $(n_N)$, each satisfying $m_N \ge N$ and $n_N \ge N$ for all $N$, we have $d(x_{m_N}, x_{n_N}) \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

This definition is indeed equivalent to the usual definition of Cauchiness, and it makes sense. However, it's also just overly complicated. The definition with the supremum is simpler, and easier to work with. Or, even simpler, you can use the usual $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition:

A sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy if, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that
$$m,n \ge N \implies d(x_m, x_n) < \varepsilon.$$

